# javascript/jQuery sort array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have an array of values that look like this:

```
var myArr = ["S1_FORM", "S3_FORM", "S2_FORM", "S2_2_FORM"];
```

I need to sort them from lowest to highest.

The way I would like this array to be is like this:

```
["S1_FORM", "S2_FORM", "S2_2_FORM", "S3_FORM"]
```

Basically these numbers should be read like: 1, 2, 2.2, 3

How could I achieve this?

I have tried using .sort() but it returns:

```
["S1_FORM", "S2_2_FORM", "S2_FORM", "S3_FORM"]
```

notice "2_2" comes before "2_". It shouldn't.

Comment: Have you made any research? Why not?

Comment: This may help... http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sorting-an-array

Comment: I have tried using .sort() and it doesn't work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort See the part about the compare function.

Answer (score 3):

```
var myArr = ["S1_FORM", "S3_FORM", "S2_FORM", "S2_2_FORM"];

var extractNumber = function(str) {
    var m = str.match(/^S(\d+)_(?:(\d+)_)?/);
    return parseFloat(m[1] + '.' + m[2])
};

myArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return extractNumber(a) - extractNumber(b);
});

console.log(myArr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LDphK/

So you're extracting a number using trivial regular expression and then sort it using [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArr = ["S1_FORM", "S3_FORM", "S2_FORM", "S2_2_FORM"];
 myArr.sort();
```

If you need another sorting logic, use jQuery. This is vanilla JavaScript solution

Comment: what if there will be `S20_` and `S3_` items?

Comment: I have tried using .sort() and it doesn't work.